# Unable to connect to a local runtime: Error loading server extension —

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to connect to a local runtime to edit [Mask R-CNN model](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/official/mask_rcnn/mask_rcnn_demo.ipynb) , but I'm getting the following error: `Error loading server extension —`.

```
jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket
[I 00:48:59.298 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Issstezac1\anaconda3\lib\site-pack
ages\jupyterlab
[I 00:48:59.298 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Issstezac1\anaconda3\share\jupy
ter\lab
[W 00:48:59.314 NotebookApp] Error loading server extension —
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Issstezac1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1670, in init_
server_extensions
        mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
      File "C:\Users\Issstezac1\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '—'
[I 00:48:59.314 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\
[I 00:48:59.314 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 00:48:59.330 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=325c5ffe303c1c7b54b2639d3c6a256550411126dbfb974
5
[I 00:48:59.330 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=325c5ffe303c1c7b54b2639d3c6a256550411126dbf
b9745
[I 00:48:59.330 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip c
onfirmation).
[C 00:48:59.392 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Issstezac1/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2716-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=325c5ffe303c1c7b54b2639d3c6a256550411126dbfb9745
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=325c5ffe303c1c7b54b2639d3c6a256550411126dbfb9745
[W 00:50:09.451 NotebookApp] Blocking Cross Origin API request for /http_over_websocket.  Origin: https:/
/colab.research.google.com, Host: localhost:8888
[W 00:50:09.451 NotebookApp] 403 GET /http_over_websocket?min_version=0.0.7&jupyter_http_over_ws_auth_url
=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F%3Ftoken%3D325c5ffe303c1c7b54b2639d3c6a256550411126dbfb9745 (::1) 0.00ms
 referer=None
[W 00:50:12.951 NotebookApp] Blocking Cross Origin API request for /http_over_websocket/diagnose.  Origin
: https://colab.research.google.com, Host: localhost:8888
[W 00:50:12.951 NotebookApp] 403 GET /http_over_websocket/diagnose?min_version=0.0.7 (::1) 0.00ms referer
=None
```

I followed every [step](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) from the documentation but I still can not connect locally. Currently, I'm using Mozilla 77.0.1 (64-bit) version. Therefore, I enabled `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` as mentioned in the specific browser settings. Even I tried the `--no-browser` flag as the [Jupyter HTTP-over-WebSocket](https://github.com/googlecolab/jupyter_http_over_ws/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting) troubleshooting suggest. What am I doing wrong?

Any further help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the notebook server on your machine is running on port 8888 and accepting requests from https://colab.research.google.com.

Try the following command

```
jupyter notebook \
  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
  --port=8888 \
  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 3):

For any one who already try the solution above and it didn't work for you

Try run **Cmd** as an **administrator** and paste

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
--port=9090 --no-browser
```

This solution works for me

Answer (score 1):

there are some reason such as

1. your browser extensions (Remove/Stop all because they are blocking you)
2. use

> jupyter notebook
> --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \   --port=9090 --no-browser