# Import error when loading Jupyter Notebook Extensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to connect a local runtime in Google Colaboratory following the guide on https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html. When running "jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=9090 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0" it produces the following error message:

```
jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket
[W 05:31:57.155 NotebookApp] Error loading server extension py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1934, in init_server_extensions
        mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py'
[I 05:31:57.157 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\data
[I 05:31:57.157 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 is running at:
[I 05:31:57.157 NotebookApp] http://localhost:9090/?token=7da2b30d93fc4e57bb4bfd4db2dcf4ce621d40f92f1f2846
[I 05:31:57.157 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:9090/?token=7da2b30d93fc4e57bb4bfd4db2dcf4ce621d40f92f1f2846
[I 05:31:57.158 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 05:31:57.161 NotebookApp]
```

The error is somewhat similar to [Error loading Jupyter Notebook Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916440/error-loading-jupyter-notebook-extensions), however jupyter_nbextensions_configurator does not seem to be involved in this case. Error is the same regardless of environment. Reinstalling jupyter and extensions does not help.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this out may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430455/unable-to-connect-to-a-local-runtime-error-loading-server-extension

Comment: Changing the port or adding --no-browser sadly does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit around in the code, I found that the extensions to be loaded are configured in:

`/.jupiter/jupyter_notebook_config.json`.

The configuration file contained a bad entry, and removing this solved the issue.

Uninstalling and reinstalling `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` reintroduces the issue.